# JDBC resultset memory not freed up

Tags: jdbc

I realized that the memory used by a `ResultSet` is not freed up even after its `close()` method is called. I absolutely need to free the memory used by `ResultSet` after extracting its data. I tried to close the connection then establish a new one, but the memory is still not freed. Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're closing everything you opened, not just the `ResultSet`. In particular, any `Statement`s, `PreparedStatement`s, etc.

Also make sure you close everything in the opposite order to opening (otherwise bugs and exceptions could occur).

See also: [this MySQL bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5022)

Alternatively, maybe java's garbage collector is to blame...